# What kind of spider is this?(Rajasthan, India)

Tags: species-identification, entomology, arachnology

[image: spider or scorpion?]

Hi there, I found this insect in India/Rajasthan. Is this a spider or scorpion? It was nearly 50 mm in length.

Answer (score 5):

That's neither a spider nor a scorpion (and, of course, not an insect). That's a [solifuge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solifugae), a different group of Arachnida.

The most common Genus of solifugae in India is [*Galeodes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galeodes), which resembles the specimen in your photo:

[image]

<sup>Genus *Galeodes*</sup>

However, narrowing it down to the Genus may be a little bit more complicated.

It's worth mentioning that, despite their frightening appearance, they are not dangerous to humans.